# How to take the inverse results of a MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a query,

`SomeCollection.collection.find(:$or => [{tags:'cool'},{tags:'awesome'},{tags:'neat'},...])`

I'd like to modify the opposite collection. So all the elements except the ones found in the previous statement. So in this example, I'd like all the results that are not `tags:'cool' || tags:'awesome' || tags:'neat' || ...`.

I tried `SomeCollection.collection.find(:$not => {:$or => [{tags:'cool'},{tags:'awesome'},{tags:'neat'},...]})` which gave syntax errors. I am also considering `SomeCollection.collection.find(:$and => [{tags:{:$ne => 'cool'}}, {tags:{:$ne => 'awesome'}}, {tags:{:$ne => 'neat'}}])` which is the explicit inverse and gives me the correct answer. Is there a short hand way to get the inverse collection?

Comment: What is the purpose of $or, are you using any other fields to filter the values?

Comment: I tried to simplify the query for this question. The $or statement is across multiple fields and has many parameters. So there are `tags`, `titles`, `descriptions`, `year`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $ne in the query.

```
SomeCollection.collection.find($or : [ {tags: {$ne:'cool}}, ..]
```

Since the values you are comparing values for the same field, you can use even $nin. The query would now look like,

```
SomeCollection.collection.find($or : [ {tags : {$nin : ['cool','awesome',..]} .. ]
```

Comment: Your second query can be reduced to `db.collection.find({tags: {$nin: [ 'cool'...` and should perform better as `$or` is a rather costly operation. You might want to update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Markus for suggestions but $or spans across other fields too which is stated in the comments above.

Comment: In this case I'd like to note that sub par to outright horrible performance is to be expected. Many `$or` conditions scales horribly.